# how to close pop up modal window in the bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-modal

```
$('#modal-createUser').modal('show');
```

**I am using this to pop up  modal window for inserting record. 
How to close this automatically after user saves data.
I tried this but it closes after just it opens.**

```
$('#modal-createUser').modal('show');//goes to other component and perform insert opearation and comes back
$('#modal-createUser').modal('hide');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write below code after getting API response.I hope it will helps you.

```
$('#modal-createUser').modal('hide');
```

Comment: @Minakshi Please accept the answer if it solved your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

When you click on save button, you call a method and in that method, you may be doing API call using HTTP method. So, in *success* callback of HTTP you should put the following code:

```
$('#modal-createUser').modal('hide');
```

Or if you are not making a server API call, then just add above code to the last in save method.

Answer (score 0):

First step you need install jquery and bootstrap by npm command.

Second you need add declare `var $ : any;` in component

And use can use `$('#modal-createUser').modal('hide');`

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-model-bootstrap-close?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btnSubmit" ).click(function(){
// write ajax/ web api call to save data.
/*you can add condition using response object in case you don't 
want to close it for any error/failure.*/
    $('#modal-createUser').modal('hide'); 
});

$("form").submit(function(){
    // write ajax/ web api call to save data.
    $('#modal-createUser').modal('hide');
});
```